# How are the ntoh functions implemented under RHEL/GCC?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, glibc, gcc4.4

A production issue has led our team to the following questions:

1. Under RHEL6 using GCC 4.4.6, how are `ntohs` and `ntohl` implemented?
2. Are the implementations known to be fast or slow?
3. How can I actually see the generated assembly code for the functions?

I know the implications behind questions may seem far-fetched and ridiculous, but I have been asked to investigate.

The hardware in question is an Intel box, little endian, 64-bit processor and compiled in 64 bit.

Comment: GCC.4.4 is a very old version of GCC. Current one is 4.8.1. You should consider upgrading your compiler (notice that C++ support improved a lot since GCC 4.4)

Comment: @Basile, 4.4 is the system compiler on RHEL6 and is supported and maintained, so it's not unreasonable to stick with it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Indeed, I use GCC 4.7.2 and 4.8.1 for most development and R&D type work, but we use 4.4 for production code because that is what is distributed with the distro.

Comment: @Charles:  I think the RHEL6 tag is relevant in this case.  Why did you remove it?

Comment: @JohnDibling, given the answers, I'd actually sooner suggest tagging with glibc than creating a tag for RHEL 6, as the functions in question as provided by glibc, not the operating system itself.

Comment: @Charles:  Fair enough.  I'll add that tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. They're provided by glibc, not GCC, look in `/usr/include/bits/byteswap.h` for the `__bswap_16` and `__bswap_32` functions, which are used when optimization is enabled (see `<netinet/in.h>` for details of how.)
2. You didn't say what architecture you're using, on a big-endian system they're no-ops, so optimally fast!  On little-endian they're architecture-specific hand-optimized assembly code.
3. Use GCC's `-save-temps` option to keep the intermediate `.s` files, or use `-S` to stop after compilation and before assembling the code, or use http://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: Sorry, quite right.  This is a x86_64 machine, so little endian.

Answer (score 12):

Do the following:

#### test.c

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
int main()
{
   volatile uint32_t x = 0x12345678;
   x = ntohl(x);
   return 0;
}
```

Then compile with:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -save-temps test.c
```

And analyze the resulting `test.s` file, or alternatively run `objdump -S test.o`.

In my machine (Ubuntu 13.4) the relevant asssembler is:

```
movl    $305419896, 12(%esp)
movl    12(%esp), %eax
bswap   %eax
movl    %eax, 12(%esp)
```

Hints:

- 305419896 is 0x12345678 in decimal.
- `12(%esp)` is the address of the volatile variable.
- All the `movl` instructions are there for the `volatile`-ness  of `x`. The only really interesting instruction is `bswap`.
- Obviously, `ntohl` is compiled as an inline-intrinsic.

Moreover, if I look at the `test.i` (precompiled output), I find that the `ntohl` is `#defined` as simply `__bswap_32()`, which is an inline function with just a call to `__builtin_bswap32()`.

Comment: +1. Also note that without the `volatile`, GCC will propagate the constant and swap it at compile time (the glibc implementation uses `builtin_constant_p` to achieve this). So the short answer to this question is "It's zero or one instructions so you can ignore it". This has been true since long before RHEL 6.

Answer (score 7):

These are implemented in glibc. Look at /usr/include/netinet/in.h.  They will most likely rely on the glibc byteswap macros (/usr/include/bits/byteswap.h on my machine)

These are implemented in assembly in my header so should be pretty fast.  For constants, this is done at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

GCC/glibc causes ntohl() and htonl() to be inlined into the calling code. Therefore, the function call overhead is avoided. Furthermore, each ntohl() or htonl() call is translated into a single bswap assembler operation. According to the "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual" bswap has both latency and throughput of "1" on all current Intel CPUs. So, only a single CPU clock is required to execute ntohl() or htonl().

ntohs() and htons() are implented as a rotation by 8 bit. This effectively swaps the two halfs of the 16-bit operand. Latency and throughput are similiar to that of bswap.